# interpretation of ひとの in ひとの布団

Tags: meaning, interpretation, literature

The English translation I have expresses this as "strange mattress", but it's not clear to me why. Is this ひと the same as 人? In the given context below, is it a short-hand way of saying "他の人の布団・自分のではない布団"? If so, does ひとの generalize to any context or object? 例：ひとの車、ひとの家、ひとの本、など。

> 「失礼ですが、私は癇症でひとの蒲団に寝るのがいやだから……少し蚤よけの工夫をやるから御免なさい」

『三四郎』の第一章

Comment: One of the meanings of 人{ひと} is "other people" (他の人): [an explanation from 知恵袋.yahoo](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12201736957) and [the entry from dictionary.goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8/#jn-185757)

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but this usage of "strange" caught my eye. Do you know when  and in what writing style this was translated?

Comment: @naruto The translation is by Jay Rubin (2009, Penguin Classics, kindle version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. ひとの蒲団 is 人の蒲団. It simply means "(other) people's 蒲団". And also yes 人の布団 = 他の人の布団.

Your English translation "strange mattress" is not wrong, but here it's "strange" as in "foreign, not belonging to self"(e.g. a stranger, estranged son), but not "strange" as in "weird, eccentric"(e.g. a strange habit)

他の例も全部正しいですよ。